# google custom search can't work

Tags: php, search

Here is the test.html file code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="zh-hans" xml:lang="zh-hans">
<head>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="fr_search">        
        <form action="cse.php"  accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post"
              id="search-theme-form">    
            <input type="text" maxlength="128" name="search_theme_form"
                id="edit-search-theme-form-1" size="15" value=""  class="form-text" />
            <input type="image" name="submit" id="edit-submit"  
                class="form-submit" src="images/search_btn_top.gif" /></div>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I put the code which generated by the http://www.google.com/cse/manage/create?hl=en. The 
"Sites to search" I entered that was  http://stackoverflow.com. When I put the generated code into the cse.php. Then put the cse.php and test.html into my local php enviroment. When I entered the text "php" into the search textbox and click the search button. But there is no any result on my search result page. What's wrong with my steps and code? thank you.

Here is the cse.php file code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
<head> 
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /> 
    <title>test search</title>
 </head> 
 <body>
     <script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi" type="text/javascript"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript">
  google.load('search', '1', {language : 'en'});
   google.setOnLoadCallback(function()
    {
       var customSearchControl = new google.search.CustomSearchControl   ('011247711644571852159:xe2ytn1hwsa');
       customSearchControl.setResultSetSize(google.search.Search.FILTERED_CSE_RESULTSET);
       customSearchControl.draw('cse');
   }, true);
      </script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.google.com/cse/style/look/default.css"
            type="text/css" />      
 <?php echo 'test'; ?>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: insufficient magic. Did the site work in the google demo before you tried to insert your own code?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure where to start with your code, but with a fresh code snippet from the [Custom Search code generator](http://www.google.com/cse/manage/create?hl=en), you can pass a query string to the `CustomSearchControl`. With code borrowed [from here](http://ajax-apis.appspot.com/two-page-search), something like this should work:

```
<div id="cse">Loading&hellip;</div>
<script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script>

    // Extract user's query from the URL
    function getQuery() {
        var url = '' + window.location;
        var queryStart = url.indexOf('?') + 1;
        if (queryStart > 0) {
            var parts = url.substr(queryStart).split('&');
            for (var i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
                if (parts[i].length > 2 && parts[i].substr(0, 2) == 'q=') {
                    return decodeURIComponent(parts[i].split('=')[1].replace(/\+/g, ' '));
                }
            }
        }
        return '';
    }

    google.load('search', '1', {language:'en' });
    google.setOnLoadCallback(function() {
        var cseControl = new google.search.CustomSearchControl('ID_GOES_HERE');
        cseControl.setResultSetSize(google.search.Search.FILTERED_CSE_RESULTSET);
        cseControl.draw('cse');
        // Execute a query based on the query string
        cseControl.execute(getQuery());
    }, true);
</script>
```

So, for example that would go in your `cse.php` page (although there's no PHP in there at this stage) and your initial page's form something like:

```
<form action="cse.php" method="get">
    <input name="q"> <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the `http://` in the sites to search bit.